# Why entity autoloading doesn't work?

Tags: entities

I'm trying to set up entity autoloading using `hook_menu` like this:

```
    $menu['e-shop/produkt/detail/%commerce_datasheet'] = array(
    'title' => t('Products'),
    'page_callback' => 'commerce_products_datasheet_detail',
    'page_arguments' => array(3),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
     );

function commerce_datasheet_load($datasheet_id) {
  return entity_load_single('commerce_datasheet',$datasheet_id);
}

function commerce_products_datasheet_detail($entity, $view_mode='full') {
    dpm($entity); 
}
```

`dpm()` function doesn't return anything, so I assume, that `$entity` is empty.

I am using latest versions on Drupal 7 and Entity API module.

Comment: It's `page callback` and `page arguments`, no underscores

Comment: @Clive: Thanks, you're right, of course. I still wasn't able to solve my problem, but at least this is corrected.

Comment: Oh, you probably need to return something from the page callback too to invoke the theme handler. Your menu/load stuff looks fine to me, that should be working

Comment: @Clive: Yes, you're right. Details are in the answer, if you're interested in my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was using another module, which provided `page callback` with higher priority. For the next time - it's advisable to install `devel` module and go to `devel/menu/item?path=<uri>` where used page callback can be clearly seen.